# push to another view controller when select a UILabel in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to push from controller view to anther one when selecting a UILabel from the first view controller, but I didn't find the triggered segue on the left side in the connections inspector.

[image]

but when I select a UITableViewCell, I can see the triggered segue on the left side as it shown in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: u can have Trigger Seques only when a Class belongs to a UIResponder, UILable is not a UIResponder..

Comment: if i want to push to anther view controller when i select a title, where do I put this title?? if the uilabel doesn't work?

Comment: may be, just have a UIButton and have it look like a UILabel..or u can always have GestureRecognizers added to the Label..

Comment: thank you, I've used UIButton instead of UILabel, and it works now :)

Answer (score 2):

you will have to use UIGesture to achieve that

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];

[urLable addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

-(void)handleSingleTap
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

ViewController* viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Bonnie's answer, you could create a manual segue in the storyboard (by ctrl-dragging from one scene to another and then giving it a unique identifier in the attribute inspector), and then in the `handleSingleTap` method manually firing it. The method would then simply be:

```
-(void)handleSingleTap
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueID" sender:self];
}
```